# UIButtons won't work  after UITapGestureRecognizer is added

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the following code where i add UITapGestureRecognizer to my view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                      action:@selector(userTapped)];

 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

My problem is that when I press other `UIButton`s (buttons were created in IB) that are on the same view as the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, nothing happens.

I suppose that i add to gestureRecognizer only one action (userTapped:), but how to add interaction with other buttons that were created?

Comment: my idea is next: i need to create some backgroundVIew and add GestureRecognizer in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

or

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
        if([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
            return NO;
        return YES;
}
```